# Отделение двоеточием или запятой оборота "Имею в виду"

Tags: пунктуация

— Вчера был у цирюльника — остался доволен стрижкой.
— А что полезного в этом действии обнаруживается?
— Я теперь гораздо привлекательнее.
— Я имею в виду: разве вы что-то сделали для блага нашего отечества?

Или

— Я имею в виду, разве вы что-то сделали для блага нашего отечества?

Answer (score 4):

*Я имею в виду (следующее): разве вы что-то сделали для блага нашего отечества?* || Приличная пауза перед разъяснением. В связи с этим сильное логическое ударение на слове "виду". Не самый удачный контекст для такой структуры.
*Я имею в виду, разве вы что-то сделали для блага нашего отечества?* || Вводное предложение. Пауза почти отсутствует. Этот вариант гораздо лучше и естественнее для русского языка.